# Invoke model logic in one UserControl from view-model in another UserControl without violating MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing WPF application keeping MVVM and using Prism. Here is simplified scheme:

[image]

I need to invoke model logic in `UserControlResult` when executing command in view-model of `UserControlButtons`. Real case: `UserControlButtons` contains buttons (and one of them triggers start of data processing), while `UserControlResult` is responsible for actual data processing and result output.

I can achieve this with event aggregator from Prism. But to allow `UserControlParent` instances working independent from each other, I need to pass them different Id values, and here I have a problem with MVVM. I will describe problem with help of concrete simplified example.

To make code simpler, I will use trivial **Messenger** class instead of event aggregator from Prism. Tuple contains Id and string payload.

```
public static class Messenger
{
    public static event EventHandler<Tuple<int, string>> DoWork;

    public static void RaiseDoWork(int id, string path)
    {
        DoWork?.Invoke(null, new Tuple<int, string>(id, path));
    }
}
```

**Model instance** subscribe to messenger for knowing when to start work (if Id correct), and notify view-model when work finished.

```
public class Model
{
    public int id;

    public Model(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;

        Messenger.DoWork += (sender, tuple) =>
        {
            if (tuple.Item1 != this.Id)
            {
                return;
            }

            var result = tuple.Item2 + " processed with id " + this.id;
            this.OnWorkCompleted(result);
        };
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> WorkCompleted;

    private void OnWorkCompleted(string path)
    {
        this.WorkCompleted?.Invoke(null, path);
    }
}
```

**`UserControlResult`** is responsible for payload processing and result output. To make code simpler, lets just trace output instead of putting it on UI. So XAML will be default.

Code-behind:

```
public partial class UserControlResult : UserControl
{    
    private ResultViewModel viewModel;

    public UserControlResult()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Init(int id)
    {
        this.viewModel = new ResultViewModel(id);
        this.DataContext = this.viewModel;
    }
}
```

View-model:

```
public class ResultViewModel
{
    private Model model;

    public ResultViewModel(int id)
    {
        this.model = new Model(id);

        this.model.WorkCompleted += path =>
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(path);
        };
    }
}
```

**`UserControlButtons`** contains buttons, one of them should start processing of model in `UserControlResult` via messenger. To make code simpler, lets omit command implementation and just show its handler.

Code-behind:

```
public partial class UserControlButtons : UserControl
{    
    private ButtonsViewModel viewModel;

    public UserControlButtons()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Init(int id)
    {
        this.viewModel = new ButtonsViewModel(id);
        this.DataContext = this.viewModel;
    }
}
```

View-model:

```
public class ButtonsViewModel
{
    private int id;

    public ButtonsViewModel(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // DelegateCommand implementation...

    private void StartWorkingCommandHandler()
    {
        Messenger.RaiseDoWork(this.id, "test path");
    }
}
```

**`UserControlParent`** contains both `UserControlResult` and `UserControlButtons`. His only role is to pass Id to them, so he doesn't even need view-model.

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <uc:UserControlResult x:Name="UserControlResult" />
    <uc:UserControlButtons x:Name="UserControlButtons" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class UserControlParent : UserControl
{    
    public UserControlParent()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Init(int id)
    {
        this.UserControlResult.Init(id);
        this.UserControlButtons.Init(id);
    }
}
```

And finally **"MainWindow"** contains two instances of `UserControlParent`. Its role to assign them different Ids.

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <uc:UserControlParent x:Name="UserControlParent1" />
    <uc:UserControlParent x:Name="UserControlParent2" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.UserControlParent1.Init(111);
        this.UserControlParent2.Init(222);
    }
}
```

This will work: pressing button in `UserControlButtons` will start working in `UserControlResult` model, and both `UserControlParent` will working correct and independend thanks to Id.

But I believe that this chain of invoking `Init` methods is **violates MVVM** because code-behind (which is *View* in MVVM) should **not** know anything about Id value (which is relative to *Model* in MVVM). Talking that, I'm sure that Id is not part of view-model, because it doesn't have any presentation in UI.

How can I pass Id value from top window to the "deepest" view-models without violating MVVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not pass this value through views. There is no reason to make your views responsible for creating view models. For example this:

```
var child1 = new ChildViewModel(111);
var child2 = new ChildViewModel(222);
var main = new MainViewModel(child1 , child2);
var window = new MainWindow { DataContext = main ; }
window.Show();
```

no longer violates MVVM and works well with DI.

Also, prism uses plugin-based architecture. You define regions in your `MainWindow`, and then implement independent modules, which are plugged into those regions at runtime. I don't see you doing any of that. I think you should spend some time reading prism documentation. If you do it right - prism will wire your views and viewmodels automatically based on convention and you won't have those problems. Personally, I hate convention-based design just as much as I hate service locators (including `ViewModelLocator`). But if you chose to use prism, you should play by its rules. Fighting it or doing it wrong will only make things worse.

Comment: I should override `App`'s `OnStartup` method to run this code, right? As for Prism - its true, I didn't spend much time on documentation yet... I'm actually only using `DelegateCommand` for now :) But I'm going to use it more heavily and as well I know we can customize this naming convention for `ViewModelLocator`. Thanks anyway, I'll wait for a while so see if any other opinions exists.

Comment: Yes, that's right.